# Problem randering recursive tree shape in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I have the below tree design rendered in a layers array. The code is working perfectly fine until I move it to another code. It is a game designed in p5.js. The code is long and contains shapes like mountains, trees, clouds, etc ...

Below is the code of the tree:

```
let branch1Layer;

function setup() 
{ 
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); 
  branch1Setup();
}

function draw() 
{ 
  background(220);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < branch1Layer.length; i++) 
  {
    image(branch1Layer[i], 200*i, height/2);
  }
}

function branch1(depth, treeSize, firstTime=false, z) 
{
  branch1Layer[z].strokeWeight(10);
  
  if (firstTime) 
  {
    branch1Layer[z].translate(branch1Layer[z].width/2, branch1Layer[z].height);
    firstTime=true;
  }
  
  branch1Layer[z].push();
  
  if (depth < 10) 
  {
    branch1Layer[z].line(0, 0, 0, -treeSize/10); // draw a line going up
    branch1Layer[z].translate(0, -treeSize/10); // move the space upwards
    branch1Layer[z].rotate(branch1Layer[z].random(-0.05, 0.05));  // random wiggle

    if (branch1Layer[z].random(1.0) < 0.6) 
    { // branching
      branch1Layer[z].rotate(0.3); // rotate to the right
      branch1Layer[z].scale(0.8); // scale down

      branch1Layer[z].push(); // now save the transform state
      branch1(depth + 1, treeSize, false, z); // start a new branch!
      branch1Layer[z].pop(); // go back to saved state

      branch1Layer[z].rotate(-0.6); // rotate back to the left

      branch1Layer[z].push(); // save state
      branch1(depth + 1, treeSize, false, z); // start a second new branch
      branch1Layer[z].pop(); // back to saved state
    } 
    else 
    { // no branch - continue at the same depth
      branch1(depth, treeSize, false, z);
    }
    
    branch1Layer[z].endShape(CLOSE);
  }
  
  branch1Layer[z].pop ();
}
  
function branch1Setup ()
{
  branch1Layer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    branch1Layer[i] = createGraphics(400, 400, P2D);
    branch1(-2, 300, true, i); 
  } 
}
```

The code should show the below shapes:

[image]

But when I move the code to another code (which is a game), The tree appear like this:

[image]

I'm not able to troubleshoot this part, I'm not able to figure out what makes the three turn into these circle shapes.

Can you please guess what could cause this issue?

What can I do to show this tree in its actual shape?

How can I troubleshoot such an issue?

I tried to remove / re-add objects in the game but no luck.

Thank you for reading.

Link to the code : https://editor.p5js.org/josefalk/sketches/Vfb9QW8Pq

best regards

Comment: Just from looking at your images, my guess is that you are overriding the stroke and fill somewhere.  Can you post an editor link to the one that doesn't work?

Comment: But it's definitely weird and you're using a `line()` function so I don't know how that becomes a circle.  Maybe with [`strokeCap()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/strokeCap) but I'm still not sure how it would get the white in the middle.

Comment: Where is the code that produces the wrong output? You don't have to show the code that works, but the code that does not work.

Comment: I tried to isolate the code, The code is making conflict with another tree.

Please have a look at the code with the issue any help is appreciated :

https://editor.p5js.org/josefalk/sketches/tJRpmW4gp

Comment: I could not add the code as a comment because it is more than the allowed limit for questions.

Comment: You have to add the code in the question. Not a link to the code, but the code itslefe.

Comment: The line which is the problem is `branch1Layer[z].endShape(CLOSE);`.  If you comment that out it will look fine.  It seems like it's closing the shape by looping back around and forming a circle.  But I can't really give you a good explanation as to why that same line didn't create any problems when it was just the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `.endShape(CLOSE)`

The line which causes trouble is `branch1Layer[z].endShape(CLOSE);`.

Here's the [description from the docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/endShape) on the `endShape()` function (emphasis added):

> The `endShape()` function is the companion to `beginShape()` and **may only be called after `beginShape()`**. When `endShape()` is called, all of the image data defined since the previous call to `beginShape()` is written into the image buffer. The constant CLOSE as the value for the mode parameter to close the shape (to connect the beginning and the end).

The `endShape()` function ends whatever shape you last started with `beginShape()`.  **Your code doesn't have `branch1Layer[z].beginShape();` anywhere.** This isn't how it's intended to be used so it's doing weird things.

##### The best way to fix this is to delete the line `branch1Layer[z].endShape(CLOSE);`.

The [`beginShape()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape) and [`endShape()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/endShape) commands are designed to be used with a series of [vertex()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/vertex) commands in between.  You aren't using vertices so you don't need to begin and end the path.  The [`.line()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/line) command which you are using will draw the complete line from start to end already.

It also draws normally if I add in a companion `branch1Layer[z].beginShape();`, but it's better to delete code which doesn't do anything.

---

I still don't fully understand:

1. How you get a circle, as it should connect the end of the shape to the beginning with a straight line.  Or do nothing?  Since there aren't any vertices.
2. Why this wasn't issue in the file where you only have the tree, since you have the same mistake in the code there.

Comment: I cleaned up your code because the `branch1Layer[z]` on every line annoyed me https://editor.p5js.org/lindapaiste/sketches/D4eaxlwit

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate it. I tried to change a lot of things, Troubleshooting it for a few days But I didn't think about the endShape(CLOSE) Function. The fact that it shows the tree as a circle, Did make me think about something else. Like circle things, AngelMode, Etc ...

I don't know how the circle. The issue was only with the tree, and It loads slower than now. (a few seconds difference until the page completely show on the browser).

Thank you for re-structuring my code, The code code is much better and more constructive.